# Okta ChatterGroups provisioning

Tags: salesforce-chatter, okta-api

Is there a way to also update Chattergroup membership when provisioning accounts directly from Okta? The documentation does not list this variable in the schema.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it at the provisioning time. Assign an Okta group to the salesforce. Edit the group under salesforce app. You should see salesforce groups showing up as public groups. Select the salesforce group.

Comment: Does that mean that a Salesforce "public group" equates to a Chatter group? In my initial testing, it didn't seem to be the same, but might have done something wrong....